# GAE＋独自ドメイン＋CloudGate

Tags: java, google-app-engine

コンソールからDatastoreのクエリを閲覧するためにGoogle Cloud Datastore APIのONが必要になりました。

その中で独自ドメイン＋CloudGateを設定/導入しているプロジェクトでのみ、クエリの読込が失敗し、データの参照ができなくなっています
（※旧コンソールのDatastore Adminに至ってはサーバーエラーになって、画面が開けもしないんですが･･･）

もし、対策等々ご存じの方いらっしゃいましたらご教授ください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

独自ドメインではなくデフォルトドメインで CloudGate を利用している場合ですが、管理ユーザが CloudGate でログインできないユーザだと 旧コンソールの DatastoreAdmin で IE だとサーバエラーとなり画面が開けず、Chrome では CloudGate のログイン画面が表示される現象に遭遇したことがあります。 (新しいコンソールは読み込みエラーが発生しました。)

CloudGate でログインできる管理ユーザですと、上記事象が改善されデータの参照ができるようになりました。

参考になれば幸いです。